# CSS border doesn't work with DIVs

Tags: css, border

Its easy to see. In example 1 all works pretty well, but when I add one line of code more in example 2), it's breaking. Why? And how I should code it?

Example 1: http://jsfiddle.net/sUtvd/154/

```
[...].tripple {
width: 90%;
margin: 5%;
}[...]
```

Example 2: http://jsfiddle.net/Ec95D/3/

```
[...].tripple {
width: 90%;
margin: 5%;
border: solid;
}[...]
```

Comment: But, wait why in second example your dont have any border value? It is about border.. Or maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 1):

Add float:left to .tripple if border should go all way around divs

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to .tripple

http://jsfiddle.net/LaN5z/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floats. When all of the child elements are floating, the parent is not aware of their height, and so collapses. Putting something like a clearfix on the parent should fix the problem. See http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ for details on the clearfix.

See http://jsfiddle.net/designingsean/Ec95D/4/ for a working example. CSS from the link is below. Then just add `.cf` to the parent element.

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
} 

.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

You could also make the parent have an `overflow` set to pretty much anything, though `auto` makes the most sense in most cases. See http://jsfiddle.net/designingsean/cx7Wg/ for a working example of that.

For more on clearfix vs overflow, check out this pretty solid SO question and answer: [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)

Answer (score 0):

You should clear your floats: you can use this standard css from HTML5 biolerplate:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/Ec95D/5/)

```
<div class="tripple clearfix">
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use a div which is to `clear:both` for these occasions. Check this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ec95D/7/

Answer (score 0):

The float property in:

```
.left, .right, .middle {
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

makes the parent div empty.  Float is a CSS positioning property.

There could be a better approach, but a simple way is to put each colored box in a table with 0 cell spacing and padding.